# how to include bootstrap in my HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

its my first week of learning coding. And I need help, to include bootstrap v5.1 in my HTML. I am learning it online and the instructor is teaching with the older version of the bootstrap, so I am unable to find the "script" she asked to include.
kindly help.

Comment: You should use the same version she uses - bootstrap v5 will behave quite differently from bootstrap v4 for instance, you will encounter a lot more confusion otherwise

Comment: there is no Bootstrap 5.1.x yet. The newest version is 5.0.2. Read the manual on how to use Bootstrap: [Bootstrap v5.0.2 Manual](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) / [Bootstrap v4.6.0 Manual](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: @tacoshy : erm, no? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/download/ latest is 5.1.3

Comment: My mistake, it wasnt listed through the usual link

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to include this in your html code between `<head> </head>`

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It's mentioned in https://getbootstrap.com/

or you can download and add it to your root or some folder and get that folder location and change src="../thatfolder/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"

Comment: you should specifically mention where to include it. The different parts have to be included at different points. Otherwise you could comment to the manual in the first palce like above.

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry about it. I edited it. Thanks. By the way my reputation is not higher than 50 so i didnt try to comment.